# how to set Arial Black font family in LESS

Tags: css, less, font-family

I use less-1.7.0.min.js. When I set Arial Black,

```
@fontFamily: Arial Black,Arial Black,Gadget,sans-serif;
```

After a CSS is generated, I got this :

```
p, span {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Arial #000000, Arial #000000, Gadget, sans-serif;
}
```

How to escape converting the color name ("Black") into color code (#000000)?

Comment: color:#000000; or use "font:" property

Answer (score 10):

LESS is trying to be helpful here and is translating `Black` into it's colour code. Try putting your font names in strings:

```
font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
```

LESS will then treat it as a string literal so won't transform it.